# How to disable slider on game pad?

Tags: gamepad

I have a gamepad that works fine in Ubuntu (from a technical point-of-view), but the slider on the gamepad is malfunctioning. I would like to simply disable the slider globally so that all applications don't see that the slider exists.

Is there a configuration file or something I can edit to do this?

---

**Edit:** any advice, clues, or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated... (Such as explaining how Ubuntu manages gamepad configurations.)

Comment: What kind of gamepad?

Comment: @DKuntz2: It's a USB gamepad (9 buttons, 1 digital axis, 2 analog axes, and one annoying slider).

Comment: That's really descriptive. What kind, brand, model, what say you. Yes, all those trivial things are important here, USB means nothing, I don't know of any gaming devices that aren't usb besides old keyboards and mouses.

Comment: @DKuntz2: Sorry, it's a Logitech WingMan with RumblePad.

Comment: I found some basic information on it - http://www.sslug.dk/~chlor/joystick/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to configure your gamepad is to use jscalibrator which should allow you to set what ever configuration you like for any gamepad or joystick:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-set-up-a-gameportgamepad-or-joystick-in-ubuntu.html